# How to add children to childnodes using jsoup document

Tags: java, android, xml, jsoup

**I am trying to create the following example.**

```
<body>
  <resources>
    <string-array name="mytest">
      <item number="1">
        <name>Testname</name>
      </item>
      <item number="2">
        <name>blaat..</name>
      </item>
    </string-array>
  </resources>
</body>
```

**I try this by doing the following:**

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("test1.xml");

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(fis, "UTF-8", "");
Node node = doc.getElementsByTag("item").get(getPosition());

fis.close();
fis = openFileInput("test2.xml");
Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse(fis, "UTF-8", "");
fis.close();

Elements test = doc2.getElementsByTag("resources");
if(test.size() < 0){
fis = openFileInput("test2.xml");
doc2 = Jsoup.parse(fis, "UTF-8", "");
fis.close();
doc2.appendElement("resources").parent();
FileOutputStream os = openFileOutput("test2.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
os.write(doc2.toString().getBytes());
os.close();

fis = openFileInput("test2.xml");
doc2 = Jsoup.parse(fis, "UTF-8", "");
fis.close();
doc2.appendChild(doc2.appendElement("string-array").attr("name", "mytest")).parent();
os = openFileOutput("test2.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
os.write(doc2.toString().getBytes());
os.close();

System.out.println("Created file\n");
}

doc2.appendChild(node);
FileOutputStream os = openFileOutput("test2.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

os.write(doc2.toString().getBytes()); 
os.close();
```

**And what i get now is:**

```
<!-- test1.xml (input) -->
<resources>
  <string-array name="firsttest">
    <item number="1">
      <name>Testname</name>
    </item>
    <item number="2">
      <name>blaat..</name>
    </item>
    <item number="3">
      <name>Next item</name>
    </item>
  </string-array>
</resources>

<!-- test2.xml (output)-->
<body>
  <resources></resources>
  <string-array name="mytest"></string-array>
  <item number="1">
    <name>Testname</name>
  </item>
  <item number="2">
    <name>blaat..</name>
  </item>
</body>
```

Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong and maybe give me some examples on how it should be done?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: To give a bit more detail: I want to copy some items from test1.xml to test2.xml. So basically the user selects a listitem that points to a number in text1.xml (item number) and that item should then be copied into the  (ITEM HERE

Comment: First, clean up your code by removing things that don't matter and naming variables in a more self-documenting way. (eg. `if(test.size() < 0)` doesn't do anything, since the size will _never_ be less than 0)

Comment: i cleaned that up in my own code, because i'm still working on fixing the problem myself. but those comments are not very helpfull i'm afraid.

Comment: Can you post what is in test2.xml?  Also, jsoup is more suited to HTML parsing versus XML parsing, but you might be able to get this to work.

Comment: I added a bit more information. test2.xml is like an output document. test1.xml has information that should be able to be copied into test2.xml when the user requests

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jsoup is generally used for parsing html, not xml, although they have same structure. By default, Jsoup parses anything, then wraps it inside `<html><body>`...`</body></html>`.

An example for your goal:

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse("");
// clear <html><body></body></html>
doc.html("");

Element e = doc.appendElement("body").appendElement("resources");

e = e.appendElement("string-array");
e.attr("name", "mytest");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Element sub = e.appendElement("item");
    sub.attr("number", Integer.toString(i));
    sub.appendElement("name").text("blahh");
}
```

References:

- [parse(String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29)
- [html(String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#html%28java.lang.String%29)
- [appendElement(String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#appendElement%28java.lang.String%29)
- [attr(String, String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#attr%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [text(String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve your exact problem, but you should be able to figure it out from here.  I do pretty much create test2.xml as a new document.  So, if that exists with information in it, you will have to work around that.

```
    String html = 
        "<resources>" +
          "<string-array name=\"firsttest\">" +
            "<item number=\"1\">" +
             "<name>Testname</name>" +
            "</item>" +
            "<item number=\"2\">" +
              "<name>blaat..</name>" +
            "</item>" +
            "<item number=\"3\">" +
              "<name>Next item</name>" +
            "</item>" +
          "</string-array>" +
        "</resources>";

    Document test1 = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Document test2 = Jsoup.parse("");
    test2.body().append("<resources>");
    test2.select("resources").append("<string-array name='mytest'>");
    test2.select("[name=mytest]").append(test1.select("item[number=1]").toString());
    test2.select("[name=mytest]").append(test1.select("item[number=2]").toString());

    System.out.println(test2.body().children());
```

Here is the output:

```
    <resources>
    <string-array name="mytest">
     <item number="1"> 
      <name>
        Testname 
      </name> 
     </item>
     <item number="2"> 
      <name>
        blaat.. 
      </name> 
     </item>
    </string-array>
    </resources>
```